# Is there scale invariance in the region of QCD aymptotic freedom?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, scale-invariance

It is said that in the deep inelastic scattering, scale invariance emerges. In the scattering of electrons off protons, this reflects the asymptotic freedom.
Now I got a question. Normally, a system has scale invariance because its correlation length becomes infinity. However, an infinite correlation length usually indicates the strong interaction. But in the QCD asymptotic freedom case, there is no interaction. How to understand that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that scale invariance requires strong interactions. After all, free scalar field theory is scale invariant (and so is classical electromagnetism). In high energy interactions approximate scale invariance emerges because asymptotic freedom implies that free field theory is indeed a useful starting point. QCD is subtle because we cannot study scattering of quarks and gluons, we have to study scattering of hadronic bound states. The beauty of deep inelastic scatering is that the cross section factorizes into a hadronic part which only depends on a single scaling variable, $x_{bj}=Q^2/(2p\cdot q)$, and a scale invariant hard scattering cross section. Note that in general, the $Q^2$ dependence is non-trivial. It is the scattering cross section at fixed $x_{bj}$ that exhibits a pure power behavior.